# не работает подкрутка страницы к элементу

Tags: jquery, css

Код для аккордеона. При клике на элемент `ul.akkordeon1 li > p` открывается блок с текстом, и элементу `ul.akkordeon1 li > p` добавляется класс `active`, при клике на неактивный блок класс active удаляется и блок с открытым контентом скрывается при этом происходит подбрасывание страницы из-за разницы объема в контенте. Решить этот момент можно подкруткой страницы к началу элемента с классом `ul.akkordeon1 li > p.active`, но код который я прописал ниже, не работает.

```
$('ul.akkordeon1 li > p').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {    //если "кликнутый" пункт неактивный:
        $('ul.akkordeon1 li > p').removeClass('active').next('div').slideUp(); //делаем неактивными все пункты и скрываем все блоки
        $(this).addClass('active'); //активируем "кликнутый" пункт
        $(this).next('div').slideDown(200); //раскрываем следующий за ним блок с описанием
        $("body").animate({ scrollTop:$('ul.akkordeon1 li > p.active').offset().top}, 600); //планировалось что при открытии новой секции экран будет прокручиваться к p.active но это не происходит 
    } else {    //иначе:
        $(this).removeClass('active').next('div').slideUp();    //скрываем данный пункт
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вы хотите определить, где находится нужный элемент:

```
$('ul.akkordeon1 li > p.active').offset().top
```

Проблема в том, что вы скрываете пункт меню с помощью `slideUp()`, это значит, что изменений фактически еще не произошло. Т.е. тот блок который должен скрыться, фактически только начал это делать и еще не скрыт. Т.е как я понимаю, вам нужно вычесть его высоту:

```
$('ul.akkordeon1 li > p.active').offset().top-$('ul.akkordeon1 li > p').removeClass('active').next('div').height()
```

Плюс ко всему разница скоростей. скрывается блок 400 мс(стандартно для `slideUp`), а анимацию скрола вы делаете 600мс. Т.е. она не успеет.

Так-же анимация может не работать из-за того, что вы прописали `$("body")`, нужно так:

```
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: .. },400);
```

Это нужно для максимальной поддержки разными браузерами.

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий код

```
$('ul.akkordeon1 li > p').click(function(){

  //если "кликнутый" пункт неактивный:
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){    

     //делаем неактивными все пункты и скрываем все блоки               
     $('ul.akkordeon1 li > p').removeClass('active').next('div').hide(); 

     //активируем "кликнутый" пункт
     $(this).addClass('active');

     //раскрываем следующий за ним блок с описанием
     $(this).next('div').slideDown(600); 

  } else {    //иначе:

      //скрываем данный пункт
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('div').slideUp();   

  }
  $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop:$('ul.akkordeon1 li > p.active').offset().top - 80}, 600); 
});
```